# Mail migration in Google Apps Account using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-email-migration

I want to migrate my mails from one Google apps account to another Google apps account using Google Apps script , if anyone know how we can achieve this please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with appscript. At most you will be able to forward messages.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use a script?

You could use DMS [Data Migration Service] in admin console. It is easy to use and now you can migrate Contacts as well. It is a Server to Server Migration, so your work won't be affected.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6003169?hl=en.

Answer (score -1):

You can use imapsync. It will move all mails and mail folder. Only problem is it doesn't do contacts, group contacts, calendar etc...so that will be a challenge. Figure that out and let me know :-)